# Delphi com TMultiView não fica com altura desejada

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Estou com dificuldades para definir a altura (Height) para um TMultiView que está definido para "surgir" a partir de baixo para cima (propriedade `DrawerOptions -> Placement = Bottom`). Meu aplicativo Android fica com a tela na horizontal (eu forço ficar na horizontal) e preciso que o MultiView apareça na parte de baixo O problema é que mesmo definindo Height = 50 (por exemplo), ele assume sempre um outro valor bem maior.

Como faço para corrigir isso?

Comment: ja que você define que deve alinha com bottom e depois força o horizontal, não seria o caso de definir para ele alinhar o left?

Comment: Não entendi o que você quis dizer. O aplicativo roda na horizontal, portanto Bottom, continua sendo a parte de baixo. Se eu alinhar em Left, obrigatoriamente o MultiView vai aparecer a partir da esquerda do aplicativo tal como deveria, não é?

Comment: Apenas acrescentando, eu já consegui fazer o MultiView aparecer na parte de baixo. O que não consigo fazer é manter o Height no valor que configurei, pois depois de compilar ele se autoconfigura.

Comment: cade o código para podermos analisar?

Comment: Não tem código... basta apenas colocar um TMultiView na tela e setar as propriedades de alinhamento. No meu caso, estou pedindo para o MultiView ficar alinhado com Bottom em uma janela horizontal e isso está ocorrendo sem problemas. O que não estou conseguindo fazer é limitar a propriedade Height do MultiView em 100px. Em tempo de design fica OK, mas depois que compila ele fica com outro tamanho maior.

Comment: Precisa de código amigo, `Design` é uma coisa, `Execução` é outra!

Comment: @JúniorMoreira, por essa eu não esperava. O componente não estava respeitando o valor setado na propriedade Height em tempo de projeto... eu nunca tinha visto isso! Fui desenvolvedor anos atrás, usando Delphi 7 quando era a melhor versão de todas, depois abandonei e voltei a precisar agora com a versão Delphi 10 e estou muito surpreso com esse comportamento. Mas OK. Resolveu o problema setando Height = 100 (por exemplo) em tempo de execução. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apenas para marcar a questão como respondida e resolvida, mas dando o devido crédito ao @JúniorMoreira, o problema foi resolvido apenas setando a propriedade `Height = XXX pixels` no MultiView, porém em tempo de execução.

OBS.: Não consegui entender o motivo do MultiView alterar em tempo de execução o valor pré-definido para Height em tempo de desenvolvimento.